# how to have a double border for a cell

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I want to display a double bordered like following image...

[image: double border - design]

The border has a dark color (magenta) and a light color (white) (not the actual colors).

I have created a custom .xib file and a custom class extending `UITableViewCell` for my table view cells.

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Then in the custom table view class, I did this...

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    UIView *cellBottom = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height, self.bounds.size.width, 1.0f)];
    cellBottom.backgroundColor = [UIColor magentaColor]; //
    [self addSubview:cellBottomView];

    // ... other code
}
```

I got the following result... there seems to be some gap between `backgroundColor` and `separatorColor`.

[image: double border - implementation]

Why is this happening? The height of `UIView` has been set to `1` and is positioned at the bottom of `UIView` as well.

If there is some better solution to this could somebody throw some light on that?

Comment: maybe you have to adjust the cell height?

Comment: Why not you are using a image for the same?

Comment: @MangeshVyas - you mean a background image for the cell? I didn't use that because the TableView has a color gradient defined as background.

Comment: Background image or even place a image above the cell and after that  place label or other things on cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michal Zygar is partially correct.

Make sure your `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*) heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)` is correctly set to the height of the view. It doesn't automatically do that for you.

The other tip I would suggest as I do it myself, is to NOT use separators. Set your separator to none, and then add in two 1px-heigh views at the top and bottom of the cell in the XIB file.
Make sure to set the autosizing for the bottom two to stick only to the bottom edge, just in case you want to change the cell's height!